# Content-Length error in Upload File to Blob Storage

Tags: azure, file-upload, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, blobstorage

I am trying to upload a file stored in my local system to the Azure blob storage account using Azure Client Library.

Using following code:

```js
const { BlobServiceClient, StorageSharedKeyCredential } = require('@azure/storage-
blob')
const fs = require('fs')

const account = '<account>'
const accountKey = '<SharedKey>'
const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey)
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
  `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
  sharedKeyCredential
)
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient('stream-test-container')
const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient('path1/path2/file.xml')
const uploadBlobResponse = blockBlobClient.upload(fs.readFileSync('demo.xml'))
console.log(uploadBlobResponse)
```

However, I am getting an error that

```js
contentLength cannot be null or undefined.
```

[image]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason you're getting this error is because you're using incorrect upload method. [`upload`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#upload_HttpRequestBody__number__BlockBlobUploadOptions_) method expects body as `HttpRequestBody` and `contentLength` parameters. Since you're not providing the value for `contentLength` parameter, you're getting this error.

Instead of `upload` method, you should use [`uploadData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#uploadData_Buffer___Blob___ArrayBuffer___ArrayBufferView__BlockBlobParallelUploadOptions_) method. It only expects a data buffer that you will get when you read the file. I just tried your code with `uploadData` method and it worked well for me.

So your code would be:

```
    const { BlobServiceClient, StorageSharedKeyCredential } = require('@azure/storage-blob')
    const fs = require('fs')
    
    const account = '<account>'
    const accountKey = '<SharedKey>'
    const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey)
    const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
      `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
      sharedKeyCredential
    )
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient('stream-test-container')
    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient('path1/path2/file.xml')
    const uploadBlobResponse = blockBlobClient.uploadData(fs.readFileSync('demo.xml'))
    console.log(uploadBlobResponse)
```